# Removing a block in DraftJS

Tags: draftjs

I am working with draft-js and trying to roll text of a block into the previous block. I have it partially working, but I am unable figure out how to remove the second block. (CodeSandbox link at bottom)

```
qwerty         qwertyasdfg
asdfg    -->   zxcvb
zxcvb
```

I am using `Modifier` to insert the next block's text into the first, which is working as expected.

```
const text = next.getText();
const pos = block.getText().length;
const insertSelection = SelectionState.createEmpty(block.getKey()).merge({
  anchorOffset: pos,
  focusOffset: pos
});
let newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
  contentState,
  insertSelection,
  text
);
```

But, I can't figure out how to remove the "next" block. Looking on Google and Stack Overflow, I have seen two different suggestions, neither of which work for me.

```
const removeSelection = SelectionState.createEmpty(next.getKey()).merge({
  focusOffset: text.length
});

// ---- OPTION 1 ----
newContentState = Modifier.removeRange(
  newContentState,
  removeSelection,
  "forward" // "backward"
);

// ---- OPTION 2 ----
newContentState = Modifier.applyEntity(
  newContentState,
  removeSelection,
  null
);
```

The outcome of each approach is

```
OPTION 1             OPTION 2
qwertyasdfg          qwertyasdfg
                     asdfg
zxcvb                zxcvb
```

Are either of these close to correct? Or am I completely missing the right approach?

Here is a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/draftjs-remove-block-fo3cn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `SelectionState` was key for Option #1. Apparently it needs to cross the block boundary. I tested it on either side and it worked, but having it go just over the end of `block` and beginning of `next` allowed me to eliminate the insert step.

```
const removeSelection = new SelectionState({
  anchorKey: block.getKey(),
  anchorOffset: block.getText().length,
  focusKey: next.getKey(),
  focusOffset: 0
});

let newContentState = Modifier.removeRange(
  contentState,
  removeSelection,
  "forward"
);
```

[Solution in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draftjs-remove-block-solution-nvk0w)